# Google Vision: Run Multiple Types of Detection on a Single Image

Tags: google-vision

Google Vision Post requests usually look like this:

```
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "content": "image base64 string..."
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As far as I know, this only supports one 'type'.
However, I want Google to analyze for two types: `LABEL_DETECTION` and `FACE_DETECTION`.

Is it possible to ask for both in one request?
I'm currently sending two seperate requests, which is kind of inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

try this one, features should be as array

```
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "content": "image base64 string..."
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        },{
          "type":"FACE_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```